# VM Network settings for a Wireless Connection of a Laptop

Tags: virtual-machine

I have an Apache Web Server installed on Ubuntu 16.04 in a VM, the problem I'm having is that my server doesn't seem to have its own IP address. I tried using  `hostname -I` but only a blank line appears, while `ifconfig` shows 127.0.0.1 and  10.0.0.2.

The problem I suspect is that it's related to the network settings of my VM since when I imported it to the computer laboratory at school, the commands `hostname -I` and `ifconfig` showed an IP address like 192.xxx.x.xx, I tried searching around but I can't find similar problems where the host machine is connected to a router via wireless connection. What can I do?

EDIT:

VM software being used is Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager

Network Settings: [image: Screen shot of network settings]

Comment: Which VM software are you using? What WM Network card emulation type is set? _Probably, lab network has DHCP server but your host PC doesn't._

Comment: @Serg, I edited in more information. My host PC doesn't have DHCP enabled, I'll look into it. thanks

Comment: @Serg, follow up question on DHCP, I've enabled it and somehow there's still no IP showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "Bridged Adapter" is used the router acts as DHCP server.

There are 2 solutions if you want to access a server located at VM from host without network connected:

1. Set adapter as Internal network [see details](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Network_Configuration_in_VirtualBox#Host-only_Networking)
   *Note: in this case Internet cannot be accessed through this interface.

   You would probably like to add another Bridged or NAT adapter to acceesss external network*
2. or NAT [details (how to setup)](http://ask.xmodulo.com/access-nat-guest-from-host-virtualbox.html)

Comment: I tried the second solution but I can't access the website of my server using my host.

Comment: Check whether your server listen incoming traffic from any IP. In my case 2nd approach works well _(just checked)_

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Helquin This is [binding settings](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/bind.html) probably in [httpd.conf](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html)